# Is finagle 5.0 published in a Maven repository which I can add to my sbt.build (sbt11)?

Tags: scala, finagle

I'm trying to use finagle in a Scala project and I'm wondering if there's a Maven repository out there which has the jars. I want to add it as a dependency and rather not compile all the stuff locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example build.sbt file for one of my projects which uses Finagle 5.0.0:

https://github.com/cb372/finagle-beanstalk/blob/d2ac139999fd49a6dc4fcd6e1097b07da234b408/build.sbt

Basically you need:

```
resolvers += "Twitter Maven repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com/"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "finagle-core" % "5.0.0"
```

When I checked a few days ago, the latest version of finagle-core available in the Maven repo was 5.3.1, so you should probably use that.

Answer (score 2):

from http://twitter.github.com/finagle/

> Note: Maven Artifacts are published to the public twitter maven repo
>   at http://maven.twttr.com.

Comment: The latest version in the public twitter maven repo is 3.0.1 -- see http://maven.twttr.com/com/twitter/finagle/3.0.1/